# How can I hide the taxonomy field for authenticated users but show it for other users in Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal-6, tags, drupal-panels, drupal-taxonomy

I have a Drupal (v6.17) Content Type which includes a Taxonomy field.  I want to hide this from ordinary Authenticated Users, but want it available to my Site Contributor role users, so they can review and then assign tags to user-created nodes.

I've tried overriding the Node Add/Edit form in Panels 3 by creating a panel variant especially for Authenticated Users, which would exclude the Taxonomy field.  However, the Taxonomy field is bundled in with the "General Form" controls - without showing this, I don't get the Title and Body fields.

Is there a way I can either include the Title and Body fields without Taxonomy, OR hide just the Taxonomy field when the authenticated user role creates a node.

I realise there's a CCK field which might be able to help me out here, but how do I tie that to the Taxonomy module?

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution that worked for me.

I use the [content taxonomy](http://drupalmodules.com/module/content-taxonomy) cck field for taxonomy in custom CCK content type. So I can use the CCK field permission module (comes bundled with CCK) to show/hide the field based on the user role.

Content taxonomy can save terms to the field table and/or to the taxonomy table(s). It also comes with different input widgets beside checkbox and select.

Regards

Mike